# Можно ли определить как был создан shared_ptr: через make_shared или через конструктор?

Tags: c++, указатели, shared-ptr

Имеем два `std::shared_ptr` указателя на объекты:

- `p1`, созданный с помощью `std::make_shared<>()`.
- `p2`, созданный с помощью конструктора класса `std::shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1 = std::make_shared<Object>("foo");
std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo"));
```

Есть куча информации о том, что поведение `p1` и `p2` несколько различается ([Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20895648/2452869), [раздел Notes на cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), и т. д.), и есть ситуации где один метод имеет преимущества перед другим.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли имея `p1` и `p2` определить во время работы программы, были ли они созданы через `std::make_shared` или через конструктор?

Если нельзя этого сказать точно, можно ли попробовать "покопаться внутри" и сделать обоснованное предположение?

Стандарт C++ не имеет значения (хоть С++23), также подойдут решения, специфичные для конкретных компиляторов, если это делает задачу проще.

Comment: Отличный вопрос!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проверял на трех стандартных библиотеках: libstdc++, libc++, и MSVC STL.

На всех трех, `make_shared` хранит мета-информацию и объект в одном блоке памяти (чтобы два раза не звать new), а при ручном выделении памяти этого не происходит.

На всех трех, `shared_ptr` хранит в себе два указателя - на объект и на мета-информацию, именно в таком порядке.

Берем второй указатель, и проверяем, указывает ли он в середину блока памяти, лежащей по первому указателю, или еще куда-то. Для этого нужно знать длину этого блока - для этого есть всякие платформо-зависимые функции (проверял только на линуксе и на mingw через wine, мака нет).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
#else // Windows and Linux
#include <malloc.h>
#endif

template <typename T>
bool is_from_make_shared(const std::shared_ptr<T> &ptr)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(ptr) == sizeof(void *) * 2);
    char *a, *b; // a is object ptr, b is control block ptr.
    std::memcpy(&a, &ptr, sizeof(char *));
    std::memcpy(&b, (char *)&ptr + sizeof(char *), sizeof(char *));

    if (a < b)
        return false;

    std::size_t size = 
    #if defined(_WIN32)
    _msize(b);
    #elif defined(__APPLE__)
    malloc_size(b);
    #else
    malloc_usable_size(b);
    #endif

    return (char *)a < b + size;
}

struct alignas(64) A {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_from_make_shared(std::make_shared<int>(42)) << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << is_from_make_shared(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))) << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << is_from_make_shared(std::make_shared<A>()) << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << is_from_make_shared(std::shared_ptr<A>(new A)) << '\n'; // 1
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141518/discussion-on-answer-by-holyblackcat-------shared-p).